# CFLAGS and LDFLAGS vs CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ldflags, cflags

in this thread

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure

someone says that CFLAGS and LDFLAGS do not work with every configure script. Why? I would like to have more explanation about this, not just the statement ;) Under which circumstances does that work and under which doesn't it? What are the causes?

He (the accepted answer) also mentions that you should use CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH instead.
What is the difference between CFLAGS and CPATH?
Similarly what is the difference between LDFLAGS and LIBRARY_PATH?

Last question: When I use LDFLAGS = whatever, don't I override previous LDFLAGS definitions that might have been made by the developer himself? Shouldn't the syntax rather be something like ./configure LDFLAGS+=/myPath ?

Answer (score 4):

`CFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS` used by `./configure`, `CPATH`/`LIBRARY_PATH` used by GCC/MinGW compiler/linker. If `./configure` is written good, it firstly get `CFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS` from environment before appending any paths to it and calling compiler/linker. In that case, you can use

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" ./configure
```

Modern `./configure`s can accept `CFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS` as parameters

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

but if `./configure` is poor or old, only `CPATH`/`LIBRARY_PATH` can help

```
CPATH=/usr/local/include LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure
CPATH=/usr/local/include LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
```

Altenatives to `CPATH`/`LIBRARY_PATH` for Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler is `INCLUDE`/`LIB`.